# ScriptIgnore Attribute Being Ignored

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, javascriptserializer, ef-fluent-api

I'm attempting to serialize a DTO however its falling down, claiming a circular reference issue - which is definitely valid. I have the following entities:

```
public class User {
    [Key]
    public int UserID { get;set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get;set; }
    // etc
    [ScriptIgnore]
    public virtual ICollection<Role> Roles { get;set; }
};

public class Role {
    [Key]
    public int RoleID { get;set; }
    // etc
    [ScriptIgnore]
    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get;set; }
};
```

Both of these entities map to their namesakes in the database, as well as an intermediate table `UserRoles` which is not brought through but is mapped as a custom `EntityTypeConfiguration`

When I come to serialize the `User` object, an error occurs saying:

`A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.User_7A469191462B9ADC27B374089E18004C2D72F0D107975B83F04E7A46145E1B1E'.`

Obviously, by looking at both the `User` and `Role` classes, they both contain collections of each other which is why a `circular reference` error is generated but I would have assumed that by adding a `ScriptIgnore` attribute against the `Users` and `Roles` members, they would be ignored in this instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, maybe I was too quick with my posting.

This is the answer:

[ScriptIgnore, JsonSerializer not paying any attention?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12013745/scriptignore-jsonserializer-not-paying-any-attention)

Using the `[ScriptIgnore(ApplyToOverrides = true)]` parameter fixes it!